# Tor node in a box

Tags: tor

Let's say I want to help the Tor network - that relies on volunteers to donate bandwidth - but I am not familiar with Linux nor am I hacker of any kind.

Is there a product like Tor node in a a box that I could simply buy and plug to my router? Or is such concept a bad idea because adversaries could sell somehow malicious nodes to enthusiastic amateurs like me?

Comment: It isn't very difficult to setup a tor node. There are step by step instructions to do so. E.g. http://en.flossmanuals.net/bypassing-censorship/ch043_setting-up-a-tor-relay/

Comment: This is in no way an InfoSec question.

Comment: There are prepackaged software bundles for Windows, if that's easier. Selling hardware would be a giant headache.

Comment: Find yourself an old PC and use that as a Tor box.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is an independent 3rd party company called Pogoclub that manufactures a device called [Safeplug](https://pogoplug.com/safeplug) that you plug into your router

Keep in mind that there are some known vulnerabilities known to this specific device, but in the configuration settings you have the option to run a tor relay.